# Scraping links off websites - R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm using RSelenium to get the page source off the archive.org website so I can scrape the links using rvest.

```
library(rvest); library(tidyverse); 
library(RSelenium); library(netstat)

remote_driver = rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                         verbose = F,
                         port = free_port())
rd = remote_driver$client
rd$open()
rd$navigate('https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories')
rd$maxWindowSize()

html = read_html(rd$getPageSource()[[1]])

get_links <- html %>%
  html_nodes('.categories-grid__category a') %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  paste0('https://web.archive.org', .)
```

It successfully scrapes the link of the original website, but misses the portion belonging to archive.org.

This is what the first example returns:

https://web.archive.orghttp://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053146

**But it's missing the the unique identifier:**

/web/20220913024354/

This is what the full link should look like:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220913024354/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053146

### **How do I get the missing portion??**

What the scraped links should look like:

https://web.archive.org/web/20220913024354/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053146

https://web.archive.org/web/20220913024425/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053150

https://web.archive.org/web/20220913024456/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053154

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean. Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories" %>% 
  read_html() %>%  
  html_elements(".categories-grid__category a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>%  
  paste0("https://web.archive.org", .)

[1] "https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053146"
[2] "https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053150"
[3] "https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053154"
[4] "https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053158"
[5] "https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053162"
[6] "https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053166"
```

Comment: Not quite. If you navigate to https://web.archive.org/web/20220913022021/http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories, all the links under each division (master 1, master 2, master 3...) will take you to the archived version of those pages. The full link to each of those archived pages is what I need.

Comment: On second thought, that is exactly what I need. I didn't see the end of the url. Thank you!